# How to do a combo box that related or any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

Let say I have two combo box:

combo box A:
A
B
C

When A is selected, the combo box B is:
A1, A2, A3, A4

When B is selected, the combo box B is:
B1, B2, B3

When C is selected, the combo box C is:
C1

if using jquery, how to implement it... or is there any better suggestions or UI design recommended? Thank you.

Comment: search for chained drop downlist. there are a ton of implementations out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201926/countries-dropdown-that-will-automatically-change-regions-option/7202009#7202009) I believe that there are more "cascading comboboxes" in the web.